# Enzyme - access Form Input to verify mounted value is reflecting props

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

Using Enzyme and Jest, if I want to have props setting the default input values of a component with 1 or more inputs, how can I access the input to verify its text value?

Using the following example, no nodes are found and I get the error

`Method “text” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead.`

**Registration component:**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Form, Row } from "react-bootstrap";

class Register extends Component {
    constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
        username: "",
        password: ""
    };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
        username: this.props.username,
        password: this.props.password
    })
    }

    onChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
        [event.target.id]: event.target.value
    })
    }

    render() {
    var registerInformation = []
    const registerValueItems = []
    const registerLabelItems = []

    registerLabelItems.push(<div key={"username"} className="labelitem"><Form.Label>Username:</Form.Label></div>)
    registerLabelItems.push(<div key={"password"} className="labelitem"><Form.Label>Password:</Form.Label></div>)

    registerValueItems.push(<Row key={"username"}><Form.Control id="username" value={this.state.username} disabled={!this.state.edit} onChange={this.onChange}/></Row>)
    registerValueItems.push(<Row key={"password"}><Form.Control id="password" value={this.state.password} disabled={!this.state.edit} onChange={this.onChange}/></Row>)


    registerInformation = (
        <div id="registerinfoarea" className="registerinfoarea">
        <div id="registerlabelarea" className="labelarea">{registerLabelItems}</div>
        <div id="registervaluearea" className="valuearea">{registerValueItems}</div>
        </div>
    )

    return (
        <div id="registerarea" className="registerarea">
        {registerInformation}
        </div>
    );
    }
}
export default Register;
```

**Test**

```
it("renders with username", () => {
const props = {username: "Santa Clause", password: "presents"}
const RegisterComponent = mount(<Register {...props}/>);

expect(RegisterComponent.find('username').text()).toEqual('Santa Clause')
});
```

Comment: `#username` should have to be there and it should be `.value()` instead.

Comment: If I use #username instead of username, it finds 2 nodes instead of 0 (as posted in the question). It seems it is finding the same node twice for some reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using Enzyme's .find() method to look the `<Row />` component instead (I am assuming that the `Row` component is rendered only once in this component).

```
expect(RegisterComponent.find(Row).text()).toEqual('Santa Clause')
```

This will allow you to look for the node that matches that component.

Comment: What if there were multiple Rows? Could I identify them by their id or key?

Comment: @simernes Yes, there are multiple ways of doing so. Do you mind posting your full code so that I can give you the appropriate way of doing it?

Comment: I've updated the question text with the full component

Comment: @simernes in this case, since since there are only 2 `<Row />` components, you can try using `RegisterComponent.find(Row).first()`, and it should return you the first node, which is the one with username

Comment: Thanks, it got me a little further, however the call to text() receives an empty string, so the test fails as it doesn't get the expected "Santa Clause", but receives "".

Comment: I got it working with the following expect(RegisterComponent.find('#username').first().render().attr('value')).toEqual('Santa Clause'), so I'm guessing the call to text isn't behaving as you would expect on input forms?

Comment: @simernes ah, yes that was my alternative solution, which is to find it by the id using `.find('#username')`.